# Flutter responsive screen

Tags: flutter, dart

Whats the best way to make a profile text( rich text ) responsive to web / mobile using flutter on clean arch project ?

I've tried to get constrains buy the Layout builder, then sized the text style by the device size.Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't size the text based on screensize.  It's already "logical pixels".  Check out this summary by Pixeltoast on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/

Comment: Ok. How should i make the appGlobal, so i don't have to call for media query every time i want to build a widget?

Comment: Read that article!  You'll never call MediaQuery again